# hibernate update vs JPA merge on detached instance

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, orm, jpa-2.0

Both will update the persistent state but

- merge will return attached instance letting the given one unchanged.
- update will attach the given instance

my question is so : will JPA merge also trigger a select (i suppose it will to get the attached instance) whereas hibernate update won't ?

please don't try to explain me things that can already be found here [What are the differences between the different saving methods in Hibernate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/161224/what-are-the-differences-between-the-different-saving-methods-in-hibernate)

Comment: I think you cannot tell generally that a JPA merge will trigger select: it depends on how the entity looks like, e.g whether it has a `@Version` field or whether the ID is generated by your code.

Comment: the spec seems indeed to say that : Any Version columns used by the entity must be checked by the persistence runtime implementation
during the merge operation and/or at flush or commit time. In the absence of Version columns there is
no additional version checking done by the persistence provider runtime during the merge operation.

Comment: so the returned attached instance is just an attached clone of the given one and is never retrieved from database ?

Comment: As I understood the spec, JPA does not force any implementation to fetch the updated row. Now about hibernate: I am not a member of Hibernate's team and cannot answer that question, but you could browse the code (for more versions) to check that. Besides, I checked a simple `merge()` and it seems indeed not to make an additional select (which makes sens when you think of performance).

Comment: Alter logging level & observe logs, you should get answer in it.